# How do I make my code wait a bit before running more code?

Tags: java, timer

I am trying to make a delay from printing out instructions and printing out a bunch of numbers. I am using java.util.Timer to do this. Please check if there is anything wrong with my code.

```
    public static int secondsPassed = 0;

static Timer timer = new Timer();
static TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run(){
        secondsPassed++;


    }
};
public static void start(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);

}
```

then later in my code:

```
    start();
    while(secondsPassed <= 1){}
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {


        int randomInteger = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println(randomInteger);

        if (Int1 == 11){
            Int1 = randomInteger;
        }else{
            if(Int2 == 11){
                Int2 = randomInteger;
            }else{
                if(Int3 == 11){
                    Int3 = randomInteger;
                }else{
                    if(Int4 == 11){
                        Int4 = randomInteger;
                    }else{
                        Int5 = randomInteger;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int Int6 = Int1+Int2+Int3+Int4+Int5;
```

I am a beginner and this is quite obviously not optimized whatsoever. The goal is to print out 5 numbers and ask for a sum of them, but I want to give the user time to read the instructions. For some reason, my code never even prints out the random integers. When I take away the while() thing it does it just fine.

How do I make my code wait 4 seconds before running another piece of code?

Comment: Most probably you have bug in while loop . Timer updates secondPassed every second, thus in 1 second your while will be false

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you can cause a delay in the current thread with the static function `Thread.sleep(x)` where x is a long in milliseconds.

Official Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)